# Fractal dimension of rank-size distribution

Tags: reference-request, fractals, dimension-theory-analysis

I analysed the size of genres reported by the metadata of my music collection.  There are a few very large ones (like "Electronic"), and very many tiny ones, with a power-law distribution.  I made a rank-size table, and from that a log-log plot with a regression line that fits the data pretty well:

[image: Rank-size distribution of music genres]

```
gnuplot> fit a*x+b "genres.txt" using (log($1)):(log($2)) via a,b
...
Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
a               = -1.05996         +/- 0.03002      (2.833%)
b               = 6.32356          +/- 0.101        (1.598%)
...
```

**Question**: what can one say about the* fractal dimension of these music genres?

(*) I don't know which of the many fractal dimensions that exist would be the most appropriate, I've struggled to find any clear reference, many are so overloaded with domain-specific irrelevancies that I can't figure out what is really going on... other keywords may be Zipf's law, rank-frequency, ...

Comment: The Hausdorff dimension of a straight line segment is 1 and, from your plot, this is the likeliest answer.

Comment: @MoisheKohan typically fractal dimensions are calculated from a limit of ratio of logarithms, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_dimension#Examples The interesting thing is the slope of the line, not the dimension of the line (which is unrelated).  The trouble is I don't know how the slope in this kind of rank-size distribution (which is a=-1.05996 for this specific example) exactly relates to commonly defined dimensions, hence the tag "reference-request".